# Do roots lead to two antiderivatives that differ in their non-constant terms?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Consider the following example:

$f'(x)= x^{-3/2}$ and $f(4)=2 $

$f'(x)= x^{-3/2}\Rightarrow \frac {x^{(-3/2) + 1}} {-1/2}  \Rightarrow$ $\frac{-2}{\sqrt x} +C =f(x)$

This is where the problem arises now if I consider $x= 4$ then I get

$$\frac{-2}{\sqrt 4} +C \Rightarrow \frac{-2}{\pm 2} +C $$

Obviously this leads to two different antiderivatives if we consider two different cases which doesn't seem right. I was told that we consider the positive number in these situations but why? And what does the negative case represent if we were to "humor" it? Your answers will appreciated. Thank you.

Also I apologize if the question title is not descriptive of the case I'm describing. If you can think of a better title go ahead and change it or let me know, just so if anyone else looks for a similar problem have an easy time finding it?

Comment: The antiderivative is $\frac{-2}{\sqrt{x}}+C$, **not** $\frac{-2}{\pm\sqrt{x}}+C$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I mean once we plug in 4, the square root of 4 is both plus and minus 2.

Comment: Then you would equally claim that the square root of $x$ is $\pm\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: OK, another tack. Does then $x^{-3/2}$ have two values? In that case it is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $y^2\,=\,x$ for $y$ has two roots, namely $y_+\,=\,+\sqrt{x}$ and $y_-\,=\,-\sqrt{x}$. That is, by convention we take $\sqrt{x}$ to mean the positive root, unless otherwise stated.

As Andre said, the derivative of $\frac{-2}{-\sqrt{x}}+C$ is **not** $f'(x)$, but $-f'(x)$, as you can easily check.

When you write $\sqrt{4}=\pm2$ you are arbitrarily introducing a second solution that actually does not fit the equation for $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The square root function only gives one result: the positive root. $\sqrt{4}=2$, not $-2$. So, the antiderivative only has one value.

The negative case would simply represent the antiderivative of $-f'(x)$. If you are unsure why the negative root is not the answer,  try using your formula to find the area between any two points on the original function. Graph the function out,  and realize that the positive square root is the only one that gives the correct area!

Comment: I know but why is the my question. Why is -2 disregarded

Comment: Because we've defined it that way. We need a function, which means one value, not two. So we define $\sqrt{x} \ge 0$. When we want the negative square root, we use $-\sqrt{x}$. When we are solving $y^2 = x$, then both are solutions, but in this problem, the positive value has been chosen. $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is by definition *only* the positive value. Anything else leads to indeterminancies.

Comment: Simply because of the nature of functions. A function is a transformation that takes any input and gives it one single output. That is why the square root just by itself is a function that can only provide one single output. By convention,  the square root is defined to return the positive root, whereas the negative root would be given by $-\sqrt x$

Comment: There should be a mathematical convention... when $\pm2  $  is treated "plus or minus," and, when it is " plus *and* minus."